# Sample Checkout With Stripe and ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, stripe-payments

I am trying to make a test payment using `Stripe` with `ASP.NET WebForm`. I am able to get the response in the test account but would like to do few more things. I know, it has been done earlier but am new to it. I've done up to this with the help of the link - [Stripe Payment](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/webforms)

API response is successful in my test account. So here is what I've done using the tutorial:

**Default.aspx:**

```
<form action="Charge.aspx" method="POST"> //Confused here a bit
  <script>
      src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="<%= stripePublishableKey %>"
      data-amount="500"
      data-name="Stripe.com"
      data-description="Sample Charge"
      data-locale="auto"
      data-zip-code="true">
  </script>
</form>
```

**Charge.aspx:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form["stripeToken"] != null)
    {
        var customers = new CustomerService();
        var charges = new ChargeService();

        var customer = customers.Create(new CustomerCreateOptions
        {
            Email = Request.Form["stripeEmail"],
            SourceToken = Request.Form["stripeToken"]
        });

        var charge = charges.Create(new ChargeCreateOptions
        {
            Amount = 500,
            Description = "Sample Charge",
            Currency = "usd",
            CustomerId = customer.Id
        });

        Console.WriteLine(charge);
    }
}
```

This is the response, I get in my account - **200 OK POST /v1/tokens**. I am also trying to get the purchase or order details to be stored in my project's database with a token generated by `Stripe`. So tried the below that creates orders in my test account:

```
StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey("##########");

var options = new OrderCreateOptions
{
   Currency = "usd",
   Email = "jenny.rosen@example.com",
   Items = new List<OrderItemOptions> {
                new OrderItemOptions {
                Type = "sku",
                Parent = "sku_EqMkslKy9JiXAc",
                Quantity = 2,
         },
    },

    Shipping = new ShippingOptions
    {
        Name = "Jenny Rosen",
        Address = new AddressOptions
        {
           Line1 = "1234 Main Street",
           City = "San Francisco",
           State = "CA",
           PostalCode = "94111",
           Country = "US",
        },
    },
 };

var service = new OrderService();
Order order = service.Create(options);
```

This creates an order in the test account but with a button from the `ASP.NET` project, so I am unable to put the card number or other info to be verified by `Stripe`. I am willing to know if I can do the check out using `ASP.NET WebForm` with all the relevant details.

Comment: https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET

Comment: If you are looking for a guide that walks you through how to get one-time payments and sell fixed-price subscriptions and provides an example of a well-working integration with Stripe, look at the demo https://techtolia.com/Stripe/New/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, currently you have a payment form that creates a payment token(representing card details). That sends the token to a backend endpoint that

1. creates a customer and saves the card details to them.
2. charges that customer's saved details a once-off amount of $5.

You also separately have code that creates an open Order on Stripe but nothing else.

What you want to do here is combine the code — instead of doing step 2 above where you create a once-off charge, you want to create the Order, and then [call the pay endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/orders/pay) and charge the customer you just created.

```
var options = new OrderPayOptions
{
  CustomerId = customer.Id,
};
var order = service.Pay(order.Id, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @karllekko. But can I able to use custom button instead of `Stripe` button to insert relevant data with the above or if you can provide any sample? My idea is just when checkout will be done, get the token and insert the token or any notification from `Stripe` as well create orders in my test account with data in my end.

Comment: There's a [custom integration](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) of Checkout you can use to trigger the card details popup with your own button, and then handle the data submission to your sever, yes. It requires writing quite a bit more Javascript though.

Comment: https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET